# What kind of a file is a "textfile" with no extension?

Tags: text-files

What kind of file is a "textfile" with no extension? - A file with text inside it, but no `.txt` at the end.

I don't understand the purpose of a file like this, but I've seen them in Github repos, commonly storing a list of words with a word on each line.

Its also possible to create one of your desktop if you create a `.txt` file and then delete the `.txt` part. On a Mac it says that its still a `Plain Text Document` if you click "get info".

So is this still exactly the same as a textfile?